# Cant 'read" files from extracted phar file

Tags: phar

i have a .phar file that i want to extract, so i can see the php files inside and read the source. But if i "unpack" the .phar file, i can see all filenames, but if i open them i cant read the code, only weird signs. i never worked before with phar so maybe you guys can help me. i tried to unpack the phar file with

```
$phar = new Phar('jtlconnector.phar');
$phar->extractTo('/var/www/html/test/unpack2');
```

but without success.

link to phar: [Phar File](https://files.fm/f/5vxc9avx)

thx :)

Comment: "This link does not contain any files"

Answer (score 0):

The link doesn't work, but can it be the case that the files are obfuscated?
If they are, you should be able to use a online code de-obfuscator(there are multiple available, such as unphp.net) to convert them to readable code.